# how to use if-then-else in kendo template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-template, kendo-autocomplete

I am using `UI for ASP.NET Core`. I have configured autocomplete widget with customized the header & item template like below

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(x => x.AccountNumber)
        .DataTextField("AccountNumber")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetData", "Lookup");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })           
        .MinLength(2)
        .Height(400)
        .HeaderTemplateId("headerTemplate")
        .TemplateId("itemTemplate"))
```

**Templates**

```
<script id="headerTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <table>
        <tr class="auto-hd-tr">
            <td class="auto-hd-td auto-td-large">Account Number</td>             
            <td class="auto-hd-td auto-td-small">State</td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>

<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-item-td auto-td-large">${AccountNumber}</td>            
            <td class="auto-item-td auto-td-small">${State}</td>               
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

When auto complete shows searched result, and if the `AccountNumber` or `State` property is null it actually shows `null` string as value.

How do i use `if-then-else` in template, so if property is null then don't show anything

**Note:**

1> I can handle this on server and set value to `string.empty` if property is null but i would like to handle it on client side.

2>Telerik has [overview of Template here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#basics). However the syntax to show property value `#= #` or `#: #` (aka hash templates) does not work.  I have to use syntax `${ }` to get it to work.
I know how to use `if-then-else` with hash template syntax. However i dont know how to use `if-then-else` with syntax `${ }`

Answer (score 1):

I just searched my code base and the only use that I have of the `${}` style is setting values such as:

```
 <script id="tmpMyViewItem" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" >
    <div class="myViewItem" id=${AccountNumber}>        
        <h3>${AccountNumber}</h3>       
    </div> 
</script>
```

In all the places where I have conditional statements the hash templates are used:

```
.ItemTemplate("#if(data.Name!='<All>'){#<img style='padding-top:3px;'.....
```

Perhaps [this link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/syntax) I have bookmarked from way back in 2011 may put things in perspective. What keeps you from using the has template style?